# Checkbox changing inside div is invoking parent click method.How to restrict it from accessing the parent method initially?

Tags: javascript, angular5

Inside  mycomponent.html

```
<div id="parent" (click)="tempParent($event)">
    <div class="checkbox margin-top-0  checkbox-primary">
        <input id="indChk2" type="checkbox" id="child"  (change)="tempchild($event);">
        <label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside mycomponent.ts

```
tempChild = (e: any) => {
        e.stopPropagation();

    }
    tempParent = (e: any) => {
      alert('i am parent')
        console.log('navigated1');

    }
```

As soon as I click checkbox it is invoking parent method.I have tried using stoppropagation inside checkbox event but it is invoking the parent first,Can anyone ls help me with this

Comment: It is because change is not click!

Comment: @epascarello same thing even if i have click in place of change

Answer (score 0):

You say to cancel the click action, but you are stopping the propagation of a change event. Best thing is to just check what was clicked and see if it is the input.

```js
function tempParent(event) {
   if (event.target.closest('.checkbox-primary')) {
     return
   }
   
   console.log("here");
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" onclick="tempParent(event)">
  <div class="checkbox margin-top-0 checkbox-primary">
    <input id="indChk2" type="checkbox" id="child" >
    <label for="indChk2" >FOO</label>
  </div>
  <p>BAR</p>
</div>
```